# Restricting users to Edit directly on SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, runwithelevatedprivileges

We have created a SharePoint framework app which adds items to SharePoint List.   As we are in client side we gave "Contribute" level Permission to all the users to edit the form (to add update the List item from form).
Is there any way to restrict the users on updating the items directly from List. We have already restricted the user on accessing the site contents page and list pages using javascript, still the users can edit the values using rest API or direct item link.

Any other approach to restrict the same and update the item on client side also will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If users have permissions to the list, they are going to be able to add items to it.  You can just try hiding the list from your users.  They will still be able to gt to it by URL. but it will not show in your site content.

Answer (score 0):

By design, users of "Contribute" level Permission have permission to update the list.

You can stop inheritance permissions on this list and set permissions separately for this list so that other users of the site who have "Contribute" Permission levels will not be able to access the list.

You can create a group in this list individually where the user has permission to make changes to the list.

List setting - Permissions for this list - stop inheritance permissions

[image]